# How to use Flask process 2 dates like Expedia?

Tags: python, flask

I just did a web page that can allow my users to use calendar pick whatever the date they want to review, and we have lots of files for each day..  But now they ask me to make the calendar just like Expedia, the user pick a start date and a end date, and i should be able to display all the files within these 2 days range, and by default, whenever user pick the start date, the end date should be the same, and the user should be able to change the end date.. Also the end date must be bigger than the start date.. 
Blow is the function that i get my file info..

```
def get_files(date):
res_files = []
path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,date)
if os.path.isfile(path):
    return res_files
if (not isdir(path)):
    return res_files
dirs = os.listdir(path)
cat_dirs = [f for f in dirs if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,f))]
for c in cat_dirs:
    abs_dir = join(path,c)
    cat_files = [f for f in os.listdir(abs_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(abs_dir,f))]
    for f in cat_files:
        abs_file = join(abs_dir, f)
        file_time = os.path.getmtime(abs_file)
        t = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(file_time))
        res_files.append((getctime(abs_file),f ,c, abs_file, t))
files = sorted(res_files, key=lambda tup:tup[0], reverse = True)
return files
pass




def get_multi_files(dates){
files = []
for date in dates:
    files.extends(get_files(date))
return files
```

'

Answer (score 0):

You are currently iterating over the files and trying to get the last modified time on a file. While this works, this would become very resource intensive as your application grows. Also finding the files in a particular date range is difficult in this way.

Instead, use a database. When a file is uploaded, create an entry for it. When a file is modified, update the entry with the last modified time.

Ideally you can have these fields:

- file_path
- title
- description
- created_at
- updated_at

In your Flask views, you can pass two dates from the front end, say `start_date` and `end_date`. Now using these two dates, you need to find the files created/modified between those two dates.

Comment: No. You will need to modify it too. Get the file path and use them.